# Can I view the doc string of a function in Python using VIM?

Tags: python, vim, docstring

Is there any way to view a function's doc string when writing Python in VIM?

For instance:

```
def MyFunction(spam):
    """A function that foobars the spam
    returns eggs"""

    return foobar(spam).eggs()
```

I'd like to be able to type `MyFunction(spam0)` and see the doc string, either as a tooltip or in the status bar or any other way that VIM allows.

Answer (score 2):

The [pythoncomplete script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1542)  is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: OK, I see that I have that as part of the existing distribution.  How can I use it?

Comment: @Nathan Use `Ctrl-x` `Ctrl-o` in the middle of typing the function/method name.