# Is there a vim plugin to peek docstring

Tags: python, vim, docstring, neovim

Do you know of a plugin that can let user peek the docstring when cursor is on a particular function or class?

I write Python and I miss that in Pycharm I can hover over a function and peek the docstring.

Comment: Requests for off-site resources like plugins are off-topic on SO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I view the doc string of a function in Python using VIM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096912/can-i-view-the-doc-string-of-a-function-in-python-using-vim)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docstring+python+vim